# The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Integer>

Tags: java

Can't make a new list in java, i read that i should use import java.util.List; Still getting the error of The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    list.add(5);
    list.add(12);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(25);
    list.add(3);
```

Comment: What exact error do you experience? Please, provide a minimal and reproducible sample. The code you have posted looks good.

Comment: Sorry i had an error in some settings i fixed it.

Comment: You probably imported the wrong `List`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with some settings so after changing them now it's working.